# Giving Login As Other User Rights through Role

Tags: administration, user-management

I removed the ability to login as another user from one from my custom roles. But now i want to give back the ability to do so and can't remember where the setting is at. Anyone wanna take a swing at what option i need to click back on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that i forgot to check the Modify All Data    option on the user profile.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the doc you are looking for [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=delegating_user_administration.htm&language=en_US):

> **Delegate User Administration | Salesforce**
>   **Delegate User Administration**   Enable delegated administrators to manage users in specified roles and all subordinate roles, assign
>   specified profiles to those users, and log in as users who have
>   granted login access to administrators.   Available in: Enterprise,
>   Performance, Unlimited, Developer, and Database.com Editions
>
> **User Permissions Needed**   To manage delegated administration: “Customize Application”   To be a delegated
>   administrator:    “View Setup and Configuration”   From Setup, click
>   Security Controls | Delegated Administration.   Select the name of an
>   existing delegated administration group.   Click Add in the User
>   Administration related list.   Use the magnifying glass lookup icon to
>   find and add roles. Delegated administrators can create and edit users
>   in these roles and all subordinated roles.   Click Save.   Click Add
>   in the Assignable Profiles related list.   Use the magnifying glass
>   lookup icon to find and add profiles. Delegated administrators can
>   assign these profiles to the users they create and edit.
>   **Note**:
>    - Delegated administrators can’t assign profiles with the “Modify All
>
> - Data” permission. Delegated administrators who are members of       multiple delegated administration groups can assign any assignable
>     profiles to any of the users in roles that they can manage.
>
> **Click  Save.**